# HTTP response content type

Tags: scala, http-headers, download, mime-types, servlet-3.0

I am implementing a file download feature via a servlet and tried using `Files.probeContentType` without success, it doesn't seem to pick up the right MIME type, so I use a default of `application/octet-stream` when that happens. In my testing, that setting seems to work ok with all the various file types like `tar, gif, gz, mp4, xml, json`, work as in the files are downloaded correctly and can be opened with their respective apps.

First question, if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong with `probeContentType` or a better way to determine the mime type, that'll be most appreciated, here are the few lines of code in Scala

```
val is = new FileInputStream(file)
val mt = Files.probeContentType(file.toPath)
val mimetype = if (mt == null) "application/octet-stream" else mt
```

Regardless, is it ok to always set the HTTP response `content-type` to  `application/octet-stream`? I have only tested with Chrome and Firefox.

**UPDATE** In case anyone is wondering, I ended up using [MimeUtil](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) courtesy of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155087/estimate-if-file-is-mime-type). It works great so far for all the file types I have thrown at it. Here's the snippet of Scala code

```
import eu.medsea.mimeutil.MimeUtil
val file = new File("path-to-your-file")
MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector")
val mt = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(file).toString
```

Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488491/how-to-accurately-determine-mime-data-from-a-file) with helpful code snippets for a few MIME type detection libraries.